Which element of a list does a string contains pandas dataframe
This is a follow up to this question, in one of the answers, it shows the following can test if a data frame column contains values from a list.
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['foo abc', 'foobar xyz', 'bar32', 'baz 45']})
terms = ['foo', 'baz']
df4[df4['col'].str.contains('|'.join(terms))]

Moreover, what I need is to find out which item in the list is contained in that column. In this example, I want the output to be like below. Is there a simple way to achieve this without using loop?
1 (since containing foo), 1, NA (i.e., doesn't contain any from the list), 2


Code
use str.extract & map
out = (df4['col'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(terms)})")[0]
                 .map({k: n for n, k in enumerate(terms, 1)})
)

out
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    2.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64


Another possible solution, which is based on the following steps:

map_terms checks each entry in the dataframe column for words present in the terms list. It splits the string into words and uses a list comprehension to create a list of matching terms. If there are matches, it returns the first match; otherwise, it returns np.nan.

The function is applied to the col column of df4 using the map method, creating a new column called res that indicates which term was found or NA if none were found.


def map_terms(x):
    terms_found = [w for w in x.split() if w in set(terms)]
    return terms_found[0] if len(terms_found) > 0 else np.nan

df4.assign(res = df4['col'].map(map_terms))

Output:
          col  res
0     foo abc  foo
1  foobar xyz  NaN
2       bar32  NaN
3      baz 45  baz

